# css container height different in firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

I’m having problems with my CSS. Basically I have a `<div>` called container which holds all the content of my site. The container runs parallel to a right hand margin of other stuff.

I need the two to align correctly at the bottom. Chrome and Safari show the container height the same and the right hand margin and container both align but in firefox the container is shorter than the right hand margin. Is there anyway I can set a seperate css condition for firefox or another way because it looks silly.

I have tried using height 100% but I can’t use this because I have javascript and other stuff which is hidden and fades in and other reasons.

```
#container {
        /* [disabled]overflow: hidden;
    */
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        /* [disabled]float: left; */
        width: 960px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;

    }

    body {
        /* [disabled]margin-right: auto; */
        /* [disabled]margin-left: auto; */
        /* [disabled]width: 1010px; */
        font-size: 11px;
        font-family: "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
        color:#3F3F3F;
        background-color: #F3F3F3;
        margin-top: 20px;
        overflow:auto;
        /* [disabled]float: left; */
    }
```

Comment: i added the body div because i was meant to say ive already tried one idea of putting an auto overflow, but that doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

**HTML**

```
<div>HEADER</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Content Area</p>
        <p>row#2</p>
        <p>row#3</p>
        <p>row#4</p>
        <p>row#5</p>
        <p>row#6</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </div>
</div>

<div>FOOTER</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;    
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content, .sidebar {
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100%;
}

.content {
    width: 68%;
    background-color: red;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 28%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

This should align the two columns to the same height.

I've made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/hHgJt/) you can try.

**EDIT**: maybe you could take a look at the article on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) that talk about different valid alternative methods.

Answer (score 0):

Without HTML it's tough to say exactly. What about putting both in a wrapper div that has a definite pixel height, then your #content and #margin divs at 100% height?

```
#wrapper{
width: 100%;
height: your height in px;
}

#container {
    /* [disabled]overflow: hidden;
*/
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    /* [disabled]float: left; */
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

#margin{
height:100%;
}
```

Also, play with all of your CSS in firebug to troubleshoot this. Removing attributes one by one to find a possible problem.